# how to convert null (of multiple columns) into 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I would like to fill all the NULL values by zero
Based on my search, I try to use coalesce.
I wrote the following code by PSQL report error:

> column "coalesce" specified more than once

I want to know why and how to fix it.

```
select country.name as name, country.electoral_system, 
       coalesce(table4_single.single_party,0), 
       coalesce(table4_two_to_three.two_to_three,0), 
       coalesce(table4_four_to_five.four_to_five,0), 
       coalesce(table4_six_or_more.six_or_more,0)
```

Comment: don't forget to specify alias - `coalesce(table4_single.single_party,0) AS single_party, ...`

Comment: For your next question, please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`.  This should work:

```
select country.name as name, country.electoral_system, 
       coalesce(table4_single.single_party, 0) as single_party, 
       coalesce(table4_two_to_three.two_to_three, 0) as two_to_three, 
       coalesce(table4_four_to_five.four_to_five, 0) as four_to_five, 
       coalesce(table4_six_or_more.six_or_more, 0) as six_or_more
from table4 join
     country
     on . . .;
```